# Laravel validate multidimensional array on dynamic fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am creating a dynamic form and hence inputs names are being created dynamically, But validation is not working properly.

Input Example:

```
<input type="text" id="information" name="page[home][Admin]user[]">
<input type="text" name="action[home][Admin]user[]">
```

Validation:

```
   $validatedData = $request->validate([     
              'page'=>'required|array',
              'page.*.user'=>'required',           
  ]);
```

But it's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing input name to

```
<input type="text" id="information" name="page[home][Admin][user][]">
```

and validation rules like

```
[
   'page'=>'required|array',
   'page.*.*.user.*'=>'required',
]
```

So Request contain page data like

```
"page" => array:1 [▼
    "home" => array:1 [▼
      "Admin" => array:1 [▼
        "user" => array:2 [▼
          0 => ""
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```